# ポスグレデータベースを、AWSのdynamodbへ移行するためまずjson形式で抜き出したいと考えています。

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-dynamodb

ポスグレデータベースを、AWSのdynamodbへ移行するためまずjson形式で抜き出したいと考えています。
そのため複数のテーブルを範囲指定し、範囲内の全てのカラムをselect文をjson形式に出力するため以下の文を考えました。

```
SELECT to_json(table_100) from table_100 date(timestamp) BETWEEN '198707050010' AND '202007052400';
```

しかしこのままではbetweenでsintax errorが出てしまいます。

ポスグレデータベースを、AWSのdynamodbへ移行する、手順、長い道のりになりますがご教授おねがいします。

Answer (score 0):

質問文に書かれてるSQLの問題点は2つほどありそうです。

この2点を対応してもまだエラーが出る場合、表示されたエラーメッセージと共に **新しく別の質問を投稿してください。**

1. 条件の前に `WHERE` が書かれていない
2. 条件の日付書式(フォーマット)が誤っている

   - 日付と時間を指定する場合、間にスペースが必要です

修正後のSQLは以下のようになるかと思います。

```sql
SELECT to_json(table_100)
FROM table_100
WHERE date(timestamp) BETWEEN '19870705 0010' AND '20200705 2400';
```

---

また、 `date()` を使用しているので、時間の指定はほぼ意味をなさないかと思います。 `'20200705 2400'` の場合、 `2020-07-06` のデータは取得できません。

`2020-07-06` のデータも取得する場合、条件を `'2020-07-06'` や `'20200706'` に変更してください。
(`'2020-07-05'` までのデータで問題なければ、修正の必要はありません)

PostgreSQLで使用可能な日付の書式の一例は、ドキュメントを参照してください。

https://www.postgresql.jp/document/12/html/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE